# Django login button turned to be logout after user logged in

Tags: django

I want to create a button which can switch between login/out

The button part on home.html:

```
 <li class="nav-item text-white">
     {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'home' %}">Logout</a>
     {% else %}
        <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'home' %}">Login</a>
     {% endif %}
 </li>
```

But I have no idea how to set with my views.py as it only show logout on home.html

```
def login_views(request):
  next = request.GET.get('next')
  form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
  if form.is_valid():
    username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, user)
    if next:
        return redirect(next)
    return redirect('/')
    context = {
    'form': form,
      }

return render(request, "login.html", context)


def home(request):
   return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using {% url 'home' %} in Logout link which redirect you to home page but since user is not logout you are not seeing the login nav or button.

In your views.py

```html
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('home_url')
```

And in template

```html
<li class="nav-item text-white">
     {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
     {% else %}
        <a class="nav-link text-black font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'home' %}">Login</a>
     {% endif %}
 </li>
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```html
from django.contrib.auth.models import auth
def login(request):
next = request.GET.get('next')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login_page_url')
    else:
    context = {
    'form': form,
      }
        return render(request, "login.html", context)
```

For more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Comment: means replace my whole login_views in views.py?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this code in these three files of your project.

> Note:- I have defined session in sign_in function of views.

(app)views.py,(app)urls.py and template file.

views.py:-

```
def index(request): #my index page template and it's view.
    return render(request, "index.html")

def sign_out(request): #my logout view
    Session.objects.all().delete()
    return render(request, "index.html")
```

urls.py:-

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('register/', views.sign_in, name='signin'),
    path('logout', views.sign_out, name="signout")
]
```

index.html:-

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if 'session_id' in request.session %}
        <p>Welcome, {{request.session.session_name}}</p>
        <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out
        </a>
    {% else %}
        <a href="/register" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Login
        </a>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```